# spring one-to-may annotation exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm using spring-boot.

I have a class named `Datum` and a class named `User`. A user can have many datum. So the relation is one-to-many from user's perspective. Now I want to design those classes.

Here is what I have tried :

```
public class Datum{
 ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
 ...
}
```

And :

```
public class User{
...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Datum> data = new HashSet<>();//i have tried list-arrayList too
...
}
```

But this gives me `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements:` error.

What are wrong here?

Comment: shouldn't  Datum have mapping like @ManyToOne

Comment: Danial can you check my answer ?

Comment: @ShaileshChandra absolutely correct, that solved my problem.. thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Datum{
 ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
 ...
}
```

**This is not a *OneToMany* relationship. This is a *ManyToOne*, by looking at your User class.**

This will do the job:

```
public class Datum {
 ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a user can have many datum, so in user class relation will be like

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private List<Datum> datums = new ArrayList<>()
```

And in `Datum` class no relation is needed.

Comment: two error 
 - javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:

Comment: another - org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.test.p.model.User, at table: datum, for columns:

Comment: You are getting error because you haven't used `@Entity` annotation on your domain class

Comment: @Danial Let me know about your output

Comment: there `@Entity` annotation from `javax.persistence.*`

Comment: @Danial  Then you shouldn't get any error, Can you post your **pom.xml**

Answer (score 0):

The One to Many relationship is a Many to One on the other side. You should map it in this way:

```
public class Datum{
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
...
}
```

And:

```
public class User{
...
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "user",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private Set<Datum> data = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

As you can see, the relation is a Many to One on the Datum side. Furthermore it should have a FetchType.LAZY to increase performance and, if can't be a Datum without user, you should also ad "orphanRemoval = true".